# AJAX jQuery doesn't display returned data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script to fetch data and load it in a div, the code works fine and display the user id list if I don't use any form value and if I don't use type="POST", but it doesn't work (no result and no console error message) when I use $_POST values :

HTML :

```
 <form name='newUser' id="searchForm" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="look_for" id="look_for">
<input type="text" name="lookage_from" id="age_from">
<input type="text" name="age_to" id="age_to">
</form>
```

fetchusers.php

```
$look_for = $_POST['look_for'];
$age_from = $_POST['age_from'];
$age_to = $_POST['age_to'];
$array = getProfilePicsList($look_for,$age_from,$age_to); //a function that select * from ...
echo json_encode($array);
```

jquery code:

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
        dataType: 'json',             //data format
        success: function(data)       //on recieve of reply
        {
            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: is that **single quot** valid or do you need to edit the question. Have you checked the console log if there's any error??

Comment: in this line `append(value.user_id');` From where `'`(single quote) came?

Comment: Define "works" and "doesn't work".  What is the actual problem?

Comment: Also, where are you even submitting data to the server?  Your AJAX call doesn't include any of the form values.

Comment: are u sure this function `getProfilePicsList()` returns data?

Comment: yes it returns, it works if I dont add any param

Comment: than add form input data into ajax request

Comment: @devpro How ? I think this is my problem

Comment: I think you forgot to set "age_from" name for "age_from" input in your HTML. You actually have "lookage_from"

Comment: somethign like that: `data: $("#searchForm").serialize(),`

Comment: @devpro thank you, this was my problem, could you please post an answer so I can vote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax request, you are missing the `data`. just add this:

```
data: $("#searchForm").serialize(),
```

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'models/fetchUsers.php', //the script to call to get data
    dataType: 'json',             //data format
    data: $("#searchForm").serialize(),
    success: function(data)       //on recieve of reply
    {
        $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
            $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
        });
    }
});
```

Without using `data` param, you can't get the values in `$_POST` array.

*Some References: 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp*

Comment: Thank you, this is what was missing

Comment: @user2997418: glad to help u